# Transition from one route to another with a different model in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a search page where we are getting different types of search results. In the list of search results I would like to use

```
{{#linkTo 'someResources.someResource' result}}{{result.Name}}{{/linkTo}}
```

And on the route `someResources.someResource` I want to use a totally different model than on the search page. How do I do that? When I click on the link for the `linkTo` it doesn't load the model again, instead it tries to use the model named `result` here.

So what I would like to do is to reload the model when I navigate to `someResources.someResource` based on the values in `result`.

The I do have a model named `App.SomeResource` and a find method for it that works if I go directly to that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is that I want a full reload of the model when doing the transition using `linkTo` won't work since that is using the model given to it. The solution to the problem is actually quite simple, just use a regular html `a`-tag instead. What I ended up doing was this:

```
<a {{bindAttr href="somePropertyInYourModel"}}>{{someTextProperty}}</a>
```

The property `somePropertyInYourModel` is a property containing the url to the new page. If the url is in the ember routes it will be as if you where typing that address in the address bar and pressing enter, but without the full reload of the page.

I think this is something that could be improved in ember, it would be much nicer if I could write something like:

```
{{#linkToRoute "resourceA.routeB" params="val1,val2,val3"}}Go here{{/linkToRoute}}
```

given I have this routes set up:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("resourceA", {{path: "/resourceA"}}, function() {
        this.route("routeB", {{path: "/:prop1/:prop2/:prop3");
    }
});
```

I would like to get:

```
<a href="#/resourceA/val1/val2/val3">Go here</a>
```

The order of the `val1,val2,val3` matters, if the order is changed they should also be changed in the final url.

Comment: Interesting solution, should come in handy sometime. Though it could be argued that reloading the entire page to reload a single model within a single page app is overkill. :)

Comment: But you are not reloading the whole page, that is the point :). If the link is in the ember context of the page and the target is within the ember application only the model will be reloaded instead of passed to the route. So the page will not reload just the model. It is like `transitionTo` or `linkTo` but you let the target resolve the model.

Comment: I see now. The the URL location is in hash-bang style, I had missed that, definitely handy. Without the hash bang it's a regular link though.

Comment: I'm using a similar construction inside a pagination mixin. Perhaps useful, the URL can be build by Ember methods like: window.location = this.router.generate('resourceA.routeB', {val1: 'foo', val2: 'bar'});

Answer (score 2):

Ember will bypass the `model()` hook when using `linkTo` as you've discovered. The assumption is that you passed a model to it, so it and will use that(`result`) as the `model`.

The next hook you can use is `setupController`. Since you have a `model` hook that works on the direct route, you can use call it directly from here.

One caveat is that you need to also allow for the direct route loading where the model will already have loaded.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  if (!model.isModel) {
    this.model().then(function(result)) {
      controller.set('model', result)
    }
  }
}
```

`model.isModel` is this check via an isModel property on the directly loaded model, which should be absent when passed with `linkTo`.

Note: the above code assumes that you are returning a `Promise` in your `model()` hook.

Comment: I realized there was a much easier solution to the problem, don't use  `linkTo` :). Instead I can just use a regular `a`-tag and bind the `href` to a property of the model, much easier and cleaner.

Comment: Might work for non-nested resource. `linkTo` also provides `LinkView` which sets the css class for the active route.

Comment: It works fine for nested resource. Doing it with a common a-tag makes the model to get loaded, almost like a page refresh and that is exactly what I want.