# why is ember not creating the object for my model correctly

Tags: ember.js

I am evaluating ember today for a project and testing it with our api. We have a post model that looks like this:

```
Hex.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    body: null,
    isEnabled: null,
    createdAt: null
});

Hex.Post.reopenClass({
    findById: function(id){
      return Ember.$.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/post/" + id, function(data){
         var post = Hex.Post.create();
         post.set('id', data.id);
         post.set('body',data.body);
         post.set('isEnabled',data.is_enabled);
         post.set('createdAt',data.created_at);
        return post;
    });
    }
});
....
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">
  <p>{{input type="text" value=id}}</p>

  <p>{{input type="text" value=isEnabled}}</p>
  <p>{{input type="text" value=header}}</p>
  <p>{{input type="text" value=created_at}}</p>
  <p>{{textarea value=body}}</p>
</script>
```

I am running the app with `LOG_TRANSITIONS: true` so I'm able to see that we are going to the correct nested route and that the correct url is being called. There is problem though in my template where it responds to the value returned by the JSON and NOT the value that is set in the findByID. This means that created_at works but createdAt doesn't or is_enabled works but isEnabled doesn't. What am I doing wrong? thx in advance

### EDIT #1

Here's the routes:

```
Hex.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        console.log('called with: ' + params.post_id);
       return Hex.Post.findById(params.post_id);
    }
});
```

### EDIT #2

how to details route is constructed:

```
this.resource('posts', function(){
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
});
```

Comment: can you show the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's my bad, i didn't see the comma in the getJSON, essentially we were returning the success to the function and the model hook, instead of to the function, then the function results to the model hook.

```
return Ember.$.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/post/" + id).then(function(data){
     var post = Hex.Post.create();
     post.set('id', data.id);
     post.set('body',data.body);
     post.set('isEnabled',data.is_enabled);
     post.set('createdAt',data.created_at);
    return post;
});
```

AKA

```
 id).then(
```

instead of

```
 id,
```

Comment: ahh, thx so much. Too many new things for me. One other quick question. Sometimes, going to the details causes the transition but a call isn't made to return the new model. Does the controller think it has all the information in this case? If yes, can I tell it to really get all the information.

Comment: Can you show me the route info for the details route, and how you link there?

Comment: thx kingpin; I updated with edit #2 above. I really appreciate any help. Ember looks cool - just need to wrap my head around it; much easier with your help :-)

Comment: And how did you navigate to the post?

Comment: should it matter? If I reload it at that specific url, shouldn't it pull the model in question. Is it trying to think that it already has it when it in fact doesn't like writing it to local storage or somethng. Ughh....

Comment: It depends, if you use a link-to in the template and the model is sent in it skips the model hook.

Comment: ahh, bummer - I see this guy had a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568799/transition-from-one-route-to-another-with-a-different-model-in-emberjs  I don't fully understand his soln though. I tried using {{}} but that's not going to do it

Comment: I've created a new question to ask this (thx for help): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590691/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-set-up-this-link-in-ember